# Accessing junk folder of Hotmail

Tags: jakarta-mail, pop3, hotmail

I just want to access all incomiing emails to my hotmail account. All incoming emails can either go in inbox or in junk folder. I could access all emails of inbox with pop3(with javamail) but could not get emails from junk folder. I have no idea how to access emails from junk folder. What I need to do is to store them in database.

Any idea ?

I would really appreciate any help !

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The POP3 protocol only supports access to a single mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access Inbox since hotmail provides POP3 access.